# overwrite file reference variable in with statement

Tags: python, scope, with-statement

I was curious if this causes any bad behaviors. I ran a test case and got no errors so I assume its OK (although probably not good practice). Just wanted to know how python deals with the issue I assumed should have existed?

```
with open("somefile.txt","r") as fileinfo:
    fileinfo = fileinfo.readlines()

print fileinfo
```

I thought overwritting "fileinfo" would cause issues exiting the with statement (raise some error about not being able to .close() a list). Does the with statement retain a local copy of the file reference? Thanks!

Comment: @Levon I don't do this. I was just wondering how python works around the issue. Just learning for learning

Comment: Ah .. ok, fair enough .. I guess it's a scoping type of question and `with`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course Python retains an internal reference to the object used in the `with` statement. Otherwise how would it work when you don't use the `as` clause?

Comment: great point. promted me to research the context manager (which had previously escaped me).

Answer (score 1):

A with statement does indeed store a local reference to the file object (although I am not positive exactly what is stored in self.gen)

Looked into the topic, specifically researching the context manager and found this which gives slightly more detail for those interested.

```
class GeneratorContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self, gen):
        # Store local copy of "file reference"
        self.gen = gen

        def __enter__(self):
            try:
                return self.gen.next()
            except StopIteration:
                raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield")

        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            if type is None:
                try:
                    self.gen.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    return
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
            else:
                try:
                    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
                    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
                except StopIteration:
                    return True
                except:
                    # only re-raise if it's *not* the exception that was
                    # passed to throw(), because __exit__() must not raise
                    # an exception unless __exit__() itself failed.  But
                    # throw() has to raise the exception to signal
                    # propagation, so this fixes the impedance mismatch 
                    # between the throw() protocol and the __exit__()
                    # protocol.
                    #
                    if sys.exc_info()[1] is not value:
                        raise

def contextmanager(func):
    def helper(*args, **kwds):
        return GeneratorContextManager(func(*args, **kwds))
           return helper
```